# Push notification is not working in android 10

Tags: android

This code is not generating the push.

```
//        intent used to click on notification
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AdminMainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```

//        custom notification view
        RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.custom_push);
        contentView.setImageViewResource(R.id.image, R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.title, "mSchooling");
        contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.text, message);
//        notification code
        final String CHANNEL_ID = "channel_02";
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, getString(R.string.app_name),
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
        }
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
                .setColor(Color.RED)
                .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                .setContentTitle("mSchooling")
                .setContent(contentView)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            builder.setChannelId(CHANNEL_ID); // Channel ID
        }
        builder.setAutoCancel(true);
        mNotificationManager.notify(1, builder.build());

Comment: can you show log of error?

Comment: I am not getting any error, the code is debugging as well but not generating the push.

Comment: Where are you generating the notification? A background service? Receiver? If you're starting from the background, then try checking if the background thread even starts

Comment: notification is coming from FCM, when i am debugging the code, line by line is running but push is not coming.

Comment: i am checking in android 10

Answer (score 0):

I am using custom layout for push in which i have a custom textview, simply i replaced the custom textview with default, push has worked .